# ng-click() in $sce.trustAsHtml doesn't work for uib-popover-html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a picker in a popover and I want to collect events by calling different functions, but the ng-click directive does not work.
I read about $ compiles directive, but it doesn't work for me, because I can not use both directives at once.

My html:

```
<button uib-popover-html="htmlPopover" class="btn btn-default">HTML Popover</button>
```

My Ctrl:

```
$scope.htmlPopover = $sce.trustAsHtml('<div class="picker">' +
    '<div class="picker-items">' +
    '<div class="picker-item" title=".fa-github"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></div>' +
    '<div class="picker-item picker-selected label label-success" title=".fa-heart">' +
    '<i class="fa fa-heart"></i></div><div class="picker-item" title=".fa-html5">' +
    '<i class="fa fa-html5"></i></div><div class="picker-item" title=".fa-css3">' +
  '<a ng-click=\"buttonClick()\"><i class="fa fa-css3"></i></a>' +
    '</div></div></div>');


$scope.buttonClick  = function(){
  console.log("Well");

};
```

My directive:

```
.directive('bindHtmlCompile', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(function () {
          return scope.$eval(attrs.bindHtmlCompile);
        }, function (value) {
          // In case value is a TrustedValueHolderType, sometimes it
          // needs to be explicitly called into a string in order to
          // get the HTML string.
          element.html(value && value.toString());
          // If scope is provided use it, otherwise use parent scope
          var compileScope = scope;
          if (attrs.bindHtmlScope) {
            compileScope = scope.$eval(attrs.bindHtmlScope);
          }
          $compile(element.contents())(compileScope);
        });
      }
    };
  }]);
```

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks  ;P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you'd need to use a template rather than an html.

Try `uib-popover-template` rather than `uib-popover-html`.

As per documentation:

> *uib-popover-html* - Takes an expression that evaluates to an HTML
>   string. Note that this HTML is not compiled. If compilation is
>   required, please use the uib-popover-template attribute option
>   instead. The user is responsible for ensuring the content is safe to
>   put into the DOM!

Comment: Yes you are right, to bind click inside uib-popover  you must use template. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think we should create only picker directive and don't need the bindHtmlCompile

```
.directive('picker', ['$compile', function($compile){
    return { 
      template: 'your picker template',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          $compile(element.contents())(scope);
      }
     }
    }]
```

Or better we don't need use compile. Use buttonClick as the directive function param

Comment: It is a good idea, but the default directive works, I prefer to use it. Thank you very much. ;D